# Running a Compiled Java Class

Tags: java

I compiled two java source codes, namely version.class and open.class

Basically, the version.class holds the public static void main clause, while the open.class is mainly a set of constructors that makes the whole program work.

Here is how I did it:

```
if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    new open();
} else if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The problem is when I run it in CMD, where I did type this:

```
java version
```

it says that the command can not find or load the main class. What is the main problem why this happens? Thank you. I was hoping this would run in CMD as well when compiled, so I could make a bat file to make the program run in CMD as well.
Edit:

Here is the whole version class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class version{
public static String input;
public static Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main (String [] args ) {
    System.out.println("========================");
    System.out.println("ANAGRAM MASTER VERSION 1.0");
    System.out.println("Created by: Janrae Mendoza");
    System.out.println("==========================");
    System.out.println("Press the corresponding letters for your desired option: ");
    System.out.println("<n> New Game");
    System.out.println("<q> Quit Game");
    input = s.nextLine();

if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    new open();
} else if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
```

}

while this is the open class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class open{

public String input;
public Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
public Random r = new Random();

//at least 25 words
public String scrambled[] = {"MICSECO", "LEPAIM", "ICHORE", "MLORTA", "TIEEXSUQI",
        "MEERTO", "DESTOAK", "MLIBOE", "PHRAPARGA", "UALBILNGI", "DOXORTHRO",
        "ZEIMESREM", "OKVEPRO", "ILAPRS", "TEMOED", "QUEMSADRAE", "LSEIMUP",
        "CREUPRO", "BLRUNDE", "CKRENO", "UIPRSUT", "BINMEHLOGO", "DRKERA",
        "SEACEDAP", "SOULEAZ"};

public String scrAns[] = {"ECONOMICS", "IMPALE", "HEROIC", "MORTAL", "EXQUISITE",
        "REMOTE", "STOCKADE", "MOBILE", "PARAGRAPH", "BILINGUAL", "ORTHRODOX",
        "MESMERIZE", "PROVOKE", "SPIRAL", "DEMOTE", "MASQUERADE", "IMPULSE",
        "PROCIRE", "BLUNDER", "RECKON", "PURSUIT", "HEMOGLOBIN", "DARKER",
        "ESCAPADE", "ZEALOUS"};

public int word;
public boolean stop = false;
public int scrnum;
public int timesplayed;

public void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public open() {
        while (stop == false) {
            sleep();
    System.out.println("Guess out the scrambled word!");
    word = r.nextInt(24);
    scrnum = word;
    System.out.println("ANAGRAM: " + scrambled[word]);
    System.out.print("YOUR ANSWER: ");
    input = s.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(scrAns[scrnum])) {
            System.out.println("You guessed the word right!");
            System.out.println("Continue playing? <y> Yes and any other keys for No");
            input = s.nextLine();
                if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                    timesplayed++;
                } else {
                                        stop = true;
                                    }
        }

        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for trying out version 1 of this game! You played " + timesplayed
                + " times! Enjoy your day, player!");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the 'main' method?  Heck, why not the whole class for both `version` and `open`.

Comment: I did the public static void main (String [] args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question , I can see that you have created two classes and they are

1. version.class
2. open.class

where from you are getting "titleScreen" class ?

You have main method only in version.class .
So , the main() method of the version.class can only be the entry point .

You can run the program in like the following :

java version titleScreen

titleScreen can be the input of this program.

Comment: wait, I edited the question, but still the problem goes the same :(

Comment: are you getting the same error if run it through an editor (eclipse or anything else) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the class containing the main method is named version you have to call

```
java version
```

Comment: but it is the public static void main (String [] args)

Comment: I don't get your comment. The main()-class is the programms "executor" therefor you'll have to run the compiled class-file containing your main()-method!

Answer (score 0):

You've said that you compiled `version.java` and `open.java` **to** `version.class` and `open.class`.

You've also said that `version.class` contains the main()-method. Therefore you'll have to run:

```
java version
```

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Comment: It says here could not find or load main class version :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated that the main method is in the class "version", if "titleScreen" is the input that you hope to give to the program the command that you should enter would be

```
java version titleScreen
```